# How to get the index of a particular object in NSMutablearray?

Tags: ios, object, indexing, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutablearray` like this (It is a JSON one )

```
{
   "notification_list":[
      {
         "TYPE":"ARTIST",
         "ID":"07",
         "DTEXT":"Now you can listen to the songs of ARTIST1",
         "ADDEDDATE":"27th June, 2013 4:44 pm."
      },
      {
         "TYPE":"BRAND",
         "ID":"http:\/\/www.me.lk\/",
         "DTEXT":"M Entertainment have been joined with Mobile Music",
         "ADDEDDATE":"27th June, 2013 3:37 pm."
      },
      {
         "TYPE":"ARTIST",
         "ID":"03",
         "DTEXT":"Now you can listen to the songs of ARTIST2",
         "ADDEDDATE":"27th June, 2013 3:37 pm."
      },
      {
         "TYPE":"ALBUM",
         "ID":"Nava Ridgma",
         "DTEXT":"Get new album of ARTIST3, Nava ridma",
         "ADDEDDATE":"27th June, 2013 3:37 pm."
      },
      {
         "TYPE":"SONG",
         "ID":"05",
         "DTEXT":"New Song added to the Mobile Music - Hanthane Kandumuduna by ARTIST5, Album - Aradhana",
         "ADDEDDATE":"27th June, 2013 3:37 pm."
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to get the index of this particular object in this `NSMutablearray`

```
{
   "TYPE":"ALBUM",
   "ID":"Nava Ridgma",
   "DTEXT":"Get new album of ARTIST3, Nava ridma",
   "ADDEDDATE":"27th June, 2013 3:37 pm."
}
```

How I can search this object from this `NSMutablearray` and get the index.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you take some pain and convert incoming JSON into objects. Once you have done it. trust me, life will be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *myArray
```

Considering myArray contain data given by you.

```
NSPredicate *thePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", @"TYPE", @"ALBUM"];
NSArray *filteredList = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePredicate];

NSDictionary *selectedDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
selectedDict = [filteredList lastObject];

int index;
index = [arr indexOfObject:selectedDict];
```

This will give you the index of dictionary having type=album.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TYPE == [cd] %@",@"ALBUM"];

NSInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
}];

NSLog(@"Index of object %d",index);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your consol describe as a Dictionary and you can get specific index of Object by `indexOfObject` of `NSMutableArray`

```
int index = [[myDic objectForKey:@"notification_list"] indexOfObject:yourSearchString];
NSLog(@"index From Array - %d", index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first you must parse JSON and save into NSMutableArray.
 [Parse JSOn tutorial:](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c)
and finally, you search type which you want in NSMutableArray.